# How to get category id of current post?

Tags: categories

I need to get the category id of the current post outside the loop. First I get the category based on the post id:

```
global $wp_query;
$postcat = get_the_category( $wp_query->post->ID );
```

Now how to get the category id? I tried: `$cat_id = $postcat->term_id;` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function catName($cat_id) {
    $cat_id = (int) $cat_id;
    $category = &get_category($cat_id);
    return $category->name;
}
function catLink($cat_id) {
    $category = get_the_category();
    $category_link = get_category_link($cat_id);
    echo $category_link;
}

function catCustom() {
   $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
    $parent = get_category($cats[1]->category_parent);
    if (is_wp_error($parent)){
        $cat = get_category($cats[0]);
      }
      else{
        $cat = $parent;
      }
    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($cat).'">'.$cat->name.'</a>';    
}
```

USE `<a href="<?php catLink(1); ?>"> <?php catName(1); ?>`

Comment: Welcome to the site, @swibo.  This answer could use a little more clarity.  Perhaps explain what you're doing and why, as well as why this answers the original question.

Answer (score 16):

When you use `get_the_category()` function to get category's data, it return the array of object so you have to access category id by passing array key, like this `$postcat[0]->term_id`

```
global $post;
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );

// try print_r($postcat) ;  

if ( ! empty( $postcat ) ) {
    echo esc_html( $postcat[0]->name );   
}
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 5):

Old post I know, but [`wp_get_post_categories`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/) is likely what you want.

```
$cats = wp_get_post_categories( get_the_ID(), array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
```

This will return an array of category IDs like so

```
array (size=3)
  0 => int 13
  1 => int 15
  2 => int 120
```

So if you just want one category ID, you can get that from the first key in the array of category IDs.

```
$category_id = $cats[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

An improvement to Govind Kumar answer, as the asker askes about **category ID**, not the *category name*. The property name of the object for category ID is "**cat_ID**".

```
// get cat ID for general view
$postcat = get_the_category( $query->post->ID );
if ( ! empty( $postcat ) ) {
 echo $postcat[0]->cat_ID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $post;
$postcat = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    if ( ! empty( $postcat ) ) {
       foreach ($postcat  as $nameCategory) {
           echo $nameCategory->name .' ';   
         }                                      
    }?>
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. Asker wanted the *ID* of the category, not a list of names printed out.